# Getting error this.httpClient.get(...).map is not a function when running ng test

Tags: angular, unit-testing

I am trying to understand how to create an htpClientSpy, as per the Angular documentation on testing services.  Currently I have this set up:

```
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { AuthService } from '../../../core/auth/auth.service';
import { PermissionsService } from '../services/permissions.api.service';
import { HttpClientTestingModule } from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

describe('PermissionsService', () => {

  let permissionsService: PermissionsService;
  let httpClientSpy: { get: jasmine.Spy };
  let authClientSpy: { get: jasmine.Spy };

  beforeEach(() => {
    httpClientSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('HttpClient', ['get']);
    authClientSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('Http', ['get']);
    permissionsService = new PermissionsService(new AuthService( <any> authClientSpy), <any> httpClientSpy);
  });

  it('should refresh global permissions using refreshGlobalPermissions', () => {
    const mockGlobalResponse = { global_actions: ['permission1', 'permission2', 'permission3']};
    httpClientSpy.get.and.returnValue(mockGlobalResponse);
    permissionsService.refreshGlobalPermissions().subscribe(
      permissions => expect(permissions).toEqual(mockGlobalResponse, 'expected global permissions'),
      fail
    );
    expect(httpClientSpy.get.calls.count()).toBe(1, 'one call');
  });
}
```

However, when I run my `ng test` from the console (and this is my only test) I get this error:

> TypeError: this.httpClient.get(...).map is not a function

From what I am finding, all I should need to do is import `map` in my *.spec.ts file but that does not seem to work.  Is there something I am missing here?

EDIT:
Service I am testing:

```
public refreshGlobalPermissions(): any {
    const globalPermissions = this.globalPermissions;
    if (globalPermissions.length === 0) {
      const url = `${this.baseUrl}?permissions`;
      return this.httpClient.get(url).map((response) => {
        this.globalPermissions = response['global_actions'];
      });
    }
    return Observable.of(true);
  }
```

Comment: Can you add the service code which you are testing..!

Comment: yes! My mistake there..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`HttpClient.get()` returns an Observable. Your production code calls `map()` on this Observable.

But in your code, your spy of the get() method doesn't return an Observable. It returns `mockGlobalResponse`, which is a POJO. So that can't possibly work.

I suggest you don't spy the HttpClient this way, and instead use the testing support dedicated to HttpClient, and [described in the documentation](https://angular.io/guide/http#testing-http-requests).

Comment: I am following the documentation for testing here: https://angular.io/guide/testing#service-tests Is that not correct?

Comment: Underneath the testing Http Services heading

Comment: It is correct. But IMHO, the dedicated HttpClient service support is more elegant. It allows testing that the actual request being sent has the right URL, method, body, headers, etc, and to flush the responses (or the errors) when you want to, in a more intuitive way. But yes, what you linked to is correct. It doesn't describe what `asyncData` does, however, and doesn't say that it must actually return a synchronous observable for the test to be correct.

Comment: Gotcha, thank you for clearing that up.  I was a bit confused what the difference is and why the site had two areas for seemingly the same type of testing.

Comment: The Angular documentation is a mess. It lacks a good structure, and is much too verbose. A lot of people contribute to various areas, at different times, without apparently coordinating.

Comment: I was able to get my testing working after using your suggestion, thank you!